# How to import Lodash in Stackblitz with angular?

Tags: angular, module, lodash

I wanted to share a problem related to lodash debounce but when i tried to use lodash in Stackbiltz (`angular project`), it is giving me module not found error.

**PROBLEM:**
I have installed lodash in the dependencies but it still giving me error:
`lodash module not found` in stackbiltz 
Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5pvrq

**WHAT I NEED?:**

I need to use lodash in stackbiltz for angular.

**UPDATE: (SOLUTION)**
@types/lodash was missing in dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that it lacks `@types/lodash`. If you install it as a dependency, the error will go off. Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5pvrq-zdg3ey?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the dependencies panel under your files list and type the dependency you want to add in your example.

I did it in your example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5pvrq-ysshvm?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: I had tried by installing lodash in dependencies but it still giving me error: 
http://prntscr.com/n5dnrt